# Spell Check in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spell-checking

Does anyone know if QGIS is going to have an in-built spell check as standard in future versions? It is one complaint I get from staff is lack of a spell check.

If not has anyone successfully found a way that the Python libraries can be tapped into and added into QGIS?

Comment: Where is the text you want to spell check? In attribute table?

Comment: attribute table and layout manager

Answer (score 4):

I had a go using python and library named [pyspellchecker](https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/).

Install process (on my system):
Find executable:

```py
import sys
sys.executable
```

Then pip:

[image]

This will print out the misspelled words for a field in the attribute table and select the feature:

```py
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
import re

layer = iface.activeLayer()
field_to_check = 'words'

#Remove all but letters and whitespaces
regex = re.compile(r"\s*[^A-Za-z]+\s*") #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105027/reg-ex-remove-non-alpha-characters-keeping-spaces

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    spell = SpellChecker()
    text = f[field_to_check]
    text = regex.sub(' ', text)
    wordlist = text.split()
    #print(wordlist)
    misspelled = spell.unknown(wordlist)
    if len(misspelled)>0:
        layer.select(f.id())
        print('Misspelled words in feature {}: {}'.format(f.id(), misspelled))
```

[image]

Comment: Very neat and compact solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgresql then there is a built-in functionality for spell-checking. It uses **text search** data type to create a token table extracted from your document or user input lexemes.

You only need to introduce a dictionary (it has some pre-defined ones) and implement the required SQL to find if the text need to be corrected and again use some SQL to correct it.

You may also use a third party library like [hunspell on github](https://github.com/postgrespro/hunspell_dicts).

Sorry, I don’t really know if qgis will implement spell-checking in future.